# I am unable to solve with Reduce, Solve, or NSolve?

Tags: equation-solving

I simply want to solve:

```
Reduce[((M*Exp[β*M*(1 - x)])/β)*((1/M) - β*x - Exp[-β*M*(1 - x)]) + (1/M) == 0, x]
```

where

```
&& x > 0 && x < 1 && β >= 0  && M > 0
```

Apparently, reduce cannot solve and `Solve` or `NSolve` gives a warning.

In the end, I just want to plot `x` versus beta.

Comment: There must be a better way than this: `expr = ((M*Exp[β*M (1 - x)])/β)*((1/M) - β*x - Exp[-β*M (1 - x)]) + (1/M); ListPlot[Map[{x, β} /.#&, Map[Last,Select[Table[ NMinimize[{Norm[ expr], x == j, β >= 0, M > 0}, {x, β, M}], {j, .02, .98, .02}], #[[1]] < 10^-6 &]]]]`  It complains about zero denominators but then selects solutions and plots x versus β.

Comment: I doubt the is an analytical solution for your equation. And if you want to use `NSolve`, you'll have to specify numeric values for all variables (except `x`, of course)

Comment: If you tighten your conditions with β >= 0.1 then the complaints about zero denominators go away while not seeming to lose any solutions.

Comment: I think the solution produced by `Solve` is satisfactory, despite the warning.

Comment: Thanks for that discovery @Bill! I will take a look.  Also, @Michael E2, how can we be sure that the solution given by Solve is satisfactory? You don't have to spell everything out, you can just give me an idea. Everyone is very helpful here and non-judgmental it seems. If this was Quora or Reddit, however, I probably would be shamed for such a question.

Comment: @Bill, Perhaps I should have mentioned that M is a fixed parameter. Either way, thanks. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As [Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36508/lukas-lang) he said it can't be found  analytical solution for your equation,only numerically.

I assume `M`value. `M` is in range `1..5`and has values:

```
Table[M, {M, 1, 5, 1/2}] // N
(* {1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3., 3.5, 4., 4.5, 5.} *)

func[x_, β_, M_] := 1/M + (E^(M (1 - x) β)M (-E^(-M (1 - x) β) + 1/M - x β))/β

ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[func[x, β, M] == 0, {M, 1, 5, 1/2}], {β, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> {"M=1", "M=1.5", "M=2", "M=2.5", "M=3", "M=3.5", 
"M=4", "M=4.5", "M=5"}]
```

[image]

I will use [Bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18890/bill) code with little improved by me.It's slow and give artifacts!.Just for the curiosity and comparison.

```
expr = ((M*Exp[β*M (1 - x)])/β)*((1/M) - β*x - Exp[-β*M (1 - x)]) + (1/M); 
ListLinePlot[Table[Map[{β, x} /. # &, Map[Last, Select[Table[
NMinimize[{Norm[expr], x == j, β >= 0}, {β, x}, 
Method -> "NelderMead"], {j, 1/100, 1, 1/100}], #[[1]] < 
10^-5 &]]], {M, 1, 5, 1/2}], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
PlotLabels -> {"M=1", "M=1.5", "M=2", "M=2.5", "M=3", "M=3.5", 
"M=4", "M=4.5", "M=5"}, AxesLabel -> {"β", "x[β]"}, AspectRatio -> 1] // Quiet
```

[image]

---

**EDITED: 02.07.2018**

Approximate solution by series at point `x=1/2` of order `3`.

```
eq = ((M*Exp[β*M*(1 - x)])/β)*((1/M) - β*x - Exp[-β*M*(1 - x)]) + (1/M);
eq1 = Series[((M*Exp[β*M*(1 - x)])/β)*((1/M) - β*x -Exp[-β*M*(1 - x)]) + 
(1/M), {x, 1/2, 3}] // Normal
sol = x /. Solve[eq1 == 0, x];(*Only first solution !!! *)

Plot[Evaluate@Table[sol[[1]], {M, 1, 5, 1/2}], {β, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
PlotLabels -> {"M=1", "M=1.5", "M=2", "M=2.5", "M=3", "M=3.5", "M=4",
"M=4.5", "M=5"}, AxesLabel -> {"β", "x[β]"}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Great plots! Thanks! I appreciate your effort. By the way, I found a potential way to evaluate this expression using a fast Fourier transform (https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijem/2015/523043/). I am not sure which way would be ideal, since I haven't used this in practice, but I guess I can just compare the results and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the complete answers other gave you, I would like to add some considerations. Defining

```
z=Exp[M (1-x) beta]
```

for the constraints on M, x, beta you have `z>=1`.
This position gives you the equation

```
beta (1-z M x)==(M-z)
```

where z depends on M, x, z. One equation in three unknowns of course cannot give a definite answer.

Comment: Thanks! And, yes, I was aware of this. M is a fixed parameter. One equation and two unknowns, provided I fix the value of M, allows me to express x in terms of beta - which was the aim